# How to set static private address for node running under VMWare?

Tags: static-ip, ubuntu-10.10, vmware-player

I am running Ubuntu 10.10 in VMWare Player under Windows 7. Each time I reboot the node, it gets a different private IP address (I can see this with ifconfig).

I would like my VMWare node to keep the same private IP address after each reboot. I am the only one behind my router.

Is this possible? If yes, how should I proceed? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your Ubuntu guest is using DHCP to get its IP, set it to use an appropriate static instead. Oh and VMWare is a company not a product, what product are you using, can you update your question and tags.

Comment: Do you have a link or a procedure describing how to 'use an appropriate static ip'? I am not a linux expert. Thanks.

Comment: Well presumably you have a static IP address already that your network staff have given you right? If so then you need to enter them into your Ubuntu box, if you're a novice then I'd suggest you use the GUI tools, it's under system/network-config if I recall correctly but if you can't find how to set this I suggest you get someone to help you in more than just this task.

Answer (score 1):

if you have multiple VMs running parallel, keep in mind the VMnet DHCP server might pass out the ip address you select. So stay under .127 (see here : [VMWare Description for host IP-configuration](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws3/doc/ws32_network10.html) )

Also - remember to set the route to the gateway for internet access.  on the commandline, that can be done with

> route add default gw

Answer (score 0):

I have found this [procedure](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/change-ubuntu-server-from-dhcp-to-a-static-ip-address/) following Chopper3's suggestion. It seems to work. I have skipped the ‘name server xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx update' step. After rebooting the node, ifconfig displays the configured private static IP address.